# Connect multiple bipolar PSUs to one torroidal transformer with center tapped secondary winding

Tags: power-supply, transformer, synthesizer

I'm currently starting my ventures into building a modular synthesizer in eurorack format and am currently using a single power supply like this with a 12V AC wall wart:

[image]

Source:
http://musicfromouterspace.com/analogsynth_new/WALLWARTSUPPLY/WALLWARTSUPPLY.php

As I will need another supply very soon and already ordered new rails for a bigger case I was thinking about using four of these supplies to be on the safe side (for an around 250 hp sized case, 10mA per hp as an estimate I found and also being reflected by the dimensions of commercially available case/supply combinations). The voltage regulators have a maximum output current of 1.5A, using four of them and splitting the modules on the different supplies would run each of them at around 250hp * 10mA/hp / 4 = 625mA. I think three would be enough as well, but using four would be easier for me to mount the power busses around the case.

The boards I created for the PSUs can also be used for a different kind of power supply:

[image]

Source:
http://musicfromouterspace.com/analogsynth_new/POWERSUPPLY2009/POWERSUPPLY2009.php

As I don't need the voltage regulation option I would stick to the 7812/7912 regulators.

Now my question is whether I can wire all four supplies safely to the same transformer? The 12V AC wall warts are quite expensive, especially if they have a high enough power rating (with the simple half bridge rectifier in the first PSU design I can only get half of the power out of them) I was looking at a transformer with ratings like 120 VA with 2x 12 V secondary each supplying up to 5A.

Here is a quick sketch of what I intended to do (only with two PSUs):

[image]

Comment: Will these power supplies share the same GND connection? Or rather, they will. Are you OK with that?

Comment: are your transformers center-tapped on the secondary or not? The first schematic says no, the others yes. If they are center-taps, you probably want something more like 6v (5v-7v, depending on topology and component quality) to get a good 12v out.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, that's fine, after the PSUs the different modules will all share the same GND connection again.

Comment: Should be OK then but the point where they join (at the transformer in your drawing) is your star earth point. Use it to avoid high currents in ground loops.

Comment: @dandavis The first schematic shows a 12V AC wall wart without a center tapped secondary and thus only two terminals, that design uses one terminal as GND and the other is split up to provide the positive and negative half each to different regulators. The second schematic is for a center-tapped secondary.

Comment: @BrianDrummond What do you mean with "star earth point"? Should I connect all the power bus boards at that place instead of behind the separate PSU boards?

Comment: aside: for audio, use a bunch of parallels caps instead of big ones; their ESR in parallel _divides_, which improves response times and make for flatter/quieter unregulated output, and usually ~3300u are most cost-effective.

Comment: "star earth point"  useful search term. I'm not going to attempt to describe it in a comment or even an answer.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I already tried that and found totally unrelated stuff, but it seems adding the quotes around that term while using google was mandatory in this case. Thank you very much!

Comment: @dandavis I was going to use some 3300 as you suggested, probably around 4 per rail per psu. Didn't know the ESR devides in that case. Thank you for that hint!

Comment: Another good audio/linear optimization is to build a bridge using 4 discrete "big buck" https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MBR2045CT-D.PDF diodes, which can give you 4 amps whilst dropping under a volt (0.4v * 2), compared to rectifier diodes which could easily eat up 1.8-2.4v. Heat is i*v, so they run a lot cooler as well. Having just an extra 1v overhead before the 7812s can make a big difference in usable clean output power; you can pull down the transformer more w/o clipping, and that last 1v or so can often yield an extra amp.